# In SugarCRM 6.5.16 and earlier get value from config

Tags: javascript, config, sugarcrm

> sugarcrm *6.5.16* and earlier in javascript retrieve config

for example the `$config['base_url']` value?

I want to avoid doing an ajax call every time I need it. Because, it seems like the values are already being loaded in the `window.SUGAR` object in javascript but I can't find it.

like if you go to your sugar instance and do a `console.log(window.SUGAR);` you'll see a bunch of objects but I can't find the one that would return config stuff.

i want to use the config_override file to house settings for like ajax urls that I would use in my javascript.

### p.s. Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load config variables, you need to use `$sugar_config`. $config won't work.

Try `echo $sugar_config['base_url'];`.